# Where do I enter my British Airways executive club number when I'm booking American Airlines?

Tags: british-airways, american-airlines, oneworld

I have an executive club number with British Airways. I should be able to use it for American Airlines since it's part of the same alliance (OneWorld), but I'm not sure where it would go on the form.

Do I change the "Program" from "AAdvantage" to "British Airways"? Is it perhaps the "Frequent Flier Number", or "Business Extra Number"? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

Select "British Airways" under the "Program" dropdown, and input your British Airways Executive Club number into the "Frequent Flier Number" field.

Comment: Adding a screenshot would make this a better answer

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : Apparently what I showed you was not the best fit to what you requested. Best way if you cannot find where to eter yout British airways club number information it is to get in touch with American Airlines direclty ( *call +44 (0)844 3699 899 if you are in the UK* ) and check with them on how you can insert your club number when booking a flight with them.

I think you can find the whole procedure [here](http://mommypoints.boardingarea.com/2013/04/24/how-to-book-american-airlines-flights-with-british-airways-avios/) that is appliable to your case. This procedure explains how you can use your AVIOS points in order to book an american airline ticket.

Comment: I do not think this is applicable. Your link describes how to pay for an AA flight with BA Avios. I want to pay for my AA flight with USD but connect the flight with BA, earning me points and OneWorld privileges. Moreover, posting a link without further explanation is discouraged as the answer will become worthless as soon as the link breaks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess i did not understand your problem very well. I will edit my post then